# Need a solution for designing my database that has some potential permutation complexity?

Tags: math, database-design

I am building a website where I need to make sure that the number of "coins" and number of "users" wont kill the database if increases too quickly. I first posted this on mathematica (thinking its a maths website, but found it it's not). If this is the wrong place, please let me know and I'll move it accordingly. However, it does boil down to solving a complex problem: will my database explode if the users increase too quickly?

Here's the problem:

I am trying to confirm if the following equations would work for my problem. The problem is that i have USERS (u) and i have COINS (c).

- There are millions of different coins.
- One user may have the same coin another user has. (i.e. both users have coin A)
- Users can trade coins with each other. (i.e. Trade coin A for coin B)
- Each user can trade any coin with another coin, so long as:

  - they don't trade a coin for the same coin (i.e. can't trade coin A for another coin A)
  - they can't trade with themselves (i.e. I can't offer my own Coin A for my own Coin B)

So, effectively, there are database rows stored in the DB:

```
trade_id | user_id | offer_id | want_id
1        | 1       | A        | B
2        | 2       | B        | C
```

So in the above data structure, user 1 wants coin A for coint B, and user 2 wants coin B for coin C. This is how I propose to store the data, and I need to know that if I get 1000 users, and each of them have 15 coins, how many relationships will get built in this table if each user offers each coin to another user. Will it explode exponentially? Will it be scalable? etc?

In the case of 2 users with 2 coins, you'd have user 1 being able to trade his two coins with the other users two coins, and vice versa. That makes it 4 total possible trade relationships that can be set up. However, keeping in mind that if user 1 offers A for B... user 2 can't offer B for A (because that relationship already exists.

What would the equation be to figure out how many TRADES can happen with U users and C coins?

Currently, I have one of two solutions, but neither seem to be 100% right. The two possible equations I have so far:

```
U! x C!
C x C x (U-1) x U
```

(where C = coins, and U = users);

Any thoughts on getting a more exact equation? How can I know without a shadow of a doubt, that if we scale to 1000 users with 10 coins each, that this table won't explode into millions of records?

Comment: Are you actually planning to store each _potential_ trade, or only each _executed_ trade, and asking whether this is a good schema? Or asking how many (potential or actual) trades could happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we just think about how many users can trade with other users. You could make a table with the allowable combinations.

```
                     user 1
                1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ...
           ________________________________
            1 | N | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y | ...
   user 2   2 | Y | N | Y | Y | Y | Y | ...
            3 | Y | Y | N | Y | Y | Y | ...
```

The total number of entries in the table is U * U, and there are U N's down the diagonal.

Theres two possibilities depending on if order matters. Is trade(user_A,user_B) is the same as trade(user_B,user_A) or not? If order matters the same the number of possible trades is the number of Y's in the table which is `U * U - U` or `(U-1) * U`. If the order is irrelevant then its half that number `(U-1) * U / 2` which are the [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). Lets assume order is irrelevant.

Now if we have two users the situation with coins is similar. Order does matter here so it is `C * (C-1)` possible trades between the users.

Finally multiply the two together `(U-1) * U * C * (C-1) / 2`.

The good thing is that this is a polynomial roughly `U^2 * C^2` so it will not grow to quickly. This thing to watch out for is if you have exponential growth, like calculating moves in chess. Your well clear of this.

One of the possibilities in your question had U! which is the number of ways to arrange U distinct objects into a sequence. This would have exponential growth.

Comment: The problem is, each user, can trade EVERY coin with EVERY OTHER users coins. So if there are 3 people with 3 coins, User A can offer his coins (1,2,3) to user B for any of his 3 coins (4,5,6). User A can offer User C the same deal and so on. User B and C can in turn trade with each other to. I swear that makes it potential, doesnt it?

Comment: Yes for three different type of coin and three uses we can have (A1,B2),(A1,B3),(A1,C2),(A1,C3), (A2,B1),(A2,B3),(A2,C1),(A2,C3), (A3,B1),(A3,B2),(A3,C1),(A3,C2), all possible trades with A and B are covered so we just need to consider B and C, (B1,C2),(B1,C3),(B2,C1),(B2,C3),(B3,C1),(B3,C2).  Thats 18 possible trades in all. Now U=3,C=3 and U * (U-1) * C * (C-1) / 2 = 3 * 2 * 3 * 2 = 18.

Answer (score 3):

There are U possible users and there are C possible coins.
Hence there are OWNS = CxU possible "coins owned by an individual".
Hence there are also OWNS "possible offerings for a trade".

But a trade is a pair of two such offerings, restricted by the rule that the two persons acting as offerer cannot be the same, and neither can the offered coin be the same.  So the number of candidates for completing a "possible offering" to form a "complete trade" is (C-1)x(U-1).

The number of possible ordered pairs that form a "full-blown trade" is thus

CxUx(C-1)x(U-1)

And then this is still to be divided by two because of the permutation issue (trades are a *set* of two (person,coin) pairs, not an ordered pair).

But pls note that this sort of question is actually an extremely silly one to worry about in the world of "real" database design !

Comment: So the fact that according to you, we'd have 9499 MILLION rows, if the site has 5000 users with 20 coins each, is no problem?

Comment: A serious designer of a trade site would never dream of recording all the "possible" trades in a database.  Instead, he'll design a database that allows every user to note just the coins he's willing to trade (usually a very small subset of the owned ones), and most likely there will not be a possibility to record "exclusives" as to who a user is willing to trade with.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know that if I get 1,000 users, and each of them have 15 coins, how many relationships will get built in this table if each user offers each coin to another user.

The most that can happen is all 1,000 users each trade all of their 15 coins, for 7,500 trades.  This is 15,000 coins up for trade (1,000 users x 15 coins).  Since it takes at least 2 coins to trade, you divide 15,000 by 2 to get the maximum number of trades, 7,500.

Your trade table is basically a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the number of users times the number of coins, divided by 2.

```
(U x C) / 2
```

I'm assuming users aren't trading for the sake of trading.  That they want particular coins and once they get the coins, won't trade again.

Also, most relational databases can handle millions and even billions of rows in a table.

Just make sure you have an index on trade id and on user id, trade id in your Trade table.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand this is that you are designing an *offer* table. I.e. user **A** may offer coin **a** in exchange for coin **b**, but not to a specific user. Any other user may take the offer. If this is the case, the maximum number of offers is proportional to the number of users *U* and the square of the number of coins *C*.

The maximum number of possible trades (disregarding direction) is

*C(C-1)/2*.

Every user can offer all the possible trades, as long as every user is offering the trades in the same direction, without any trade being matched. So the absolute maximum number of records in the *offer* table is

*C(C-1)/2*U*.

---

If trades are allowed between more than two user the number decreases above half that though. E.g. if **A** offers **a** for **b**, **B** offers **b** for **c** and **C** offers **c** for **a**. Then a trade could be accomplished in a triangle by **A** getting **b** from **B**, **B** getting **c** from **C** and **C** getting **a** from **A**.

The maximum number of rows in the table can then be calculated by splitting the *C* coins into two groups and offering any coin it the first group in exchange any coin in the second. We get the maximum number of combination if the groups are of the same size, *C/2*. The number of combinations is

*C/2*C/2 = C^2/4*.

Every user may offer all these trades without there being any possible trade. So the maximum number of rows is

*C^2/4*U*

which is just over half of

*C(C-1)/2*U = 2*(C^2/4*U) - C/2*U*.